# Error: FastReport.Utils.CompilerException

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

FastReport.Utils.CompilerException: '(Text3):

Error CS0246:

> The type or namespace name 'PropertyType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm trying to create report and register a Data class with a property of another Type.

```
public class Data
{
  public PropertyType PropertyName {get;set;}
}
```

And then I registered a datasource

```
report.RegisterData(Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Data), 1), TypeName, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in adding necessary namespaces in report.ScriptText by code.